# OpenCV error SVM identifier undefined

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got an issue with OpenCV 3.0.0. 
I have built it from sources with Cmake and Visual Studio 2013, because I needed to add a loading method from a "string" in the "StatModel" class. To do so, I edited the "ml.hpp" file (where there is already a "load" method).

I'm trying to use the library in a C++/CLI project. Everything is fine with classes like "Mat" for exemple, but when I use "SVM" in my code, Visual Studio show me this error: 
     IntelliSense: identifier "SVM" undefined
The funny thing is that I can access to the definition of it with a right-click and get a defined identifier with cv::ml::SVM.

The tutorial I followed to link OpenCV libraries in my project can be seen [here](http://youtu.be/vwhTKsvHwfQ). 
I don't know what is wrong with it and didn't found anything related, perhaps I miss something related to my edit? 
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of [opencv3.0](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html), you will have to use:

```
Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
```

(no, you can't use a 'stack instance, like `SVM svm;` anymore. also note the additional namespace)

(( also, if all you got is a youtube video, you basically got *nothing* ))

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll check that.
(I used the Youtube video to configure links with OpenCV because I'm not use to Visual Studio, which I am currently forced to use)

Comment: Indeed, didn't saw that everything changed for this version!
This was a stupid question... Sorry for that, but thank you very much for your answer!